# How to assign variable to a column based on a condition from another column?

Tags: python

I have 2 datasets, which look like this:

1. Dataset 1

| Link | Domain |
| --- | --- |
| https//:example/page/uk | example |
| https//:another.good-example.com | good-example |

2. Dataset 2

| ID | Domain | Ad Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | smth | NaN |
| 2 | example | NaN |
| 3 | good-example | NaN |
| 4 | another-smth | NaN |

What i need is if Domain in Dataset 2 is in Dataset 1, then Ad Source should be 'Adwords'
So, the end result is:

| ID | Domain | Ad Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | smth | NaN |
| 2 | example | Adwords |
| 3 | good-example | Adwords |
| 4 | another-smth | NaN |

I have tried this, but it didn't work:

```
for links in Dataset1['Domain']:
    if links in Dataset2['Domain']:
        return Dataset2['Ad Source']='Adwords'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing and `isin` to check domains:

```
Dataset2.loc[Dataset2['Domain'].isin(Dataset1['Domain']), 'Ad Source'] = 'Adwords'
print(Dataset2)

# Output
   ID        Domain Ad Source
0   1          smth       NaN
1   2       example   Adwords
2   3  good-example   Adwords
3   4  another-smth       NaN
```

Comment: I opened new account, so I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry(